# AppleScript error Can't make path into type alias

Tags: applescript

I’m trying to set up an AppleScript that will get a path from a txt file(mockUPPath.txt) on the Desktop which in theory will allow me to attach a jpg. The name of the folder and jpg will change so I can’t hard code it. I also get the body of the email from another text file on the Desktop which I managed to get working. I can get it to build the email but not find and attach the jpg.

The text in the mockUPPath.txt file looks like this: Name_Mock-up/555.jpg.
The jpg 555.jpg is in a folder “Name_Mock-up” on the Desktop
This is what I have so far (below), anyone know where I’m going wrong?

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to return
set theFile to ((path to desktop as text) & "mockUPText.txt")
set theData to paragraphs of (read file theFile)

set myPath to ((path to desktop as text) & "mockUPPath.txt")
set thePath to paragraphs of (read file myPath)
set newPath to (POSIX path of (path to desktop folder)) & thePath


--Email

set theMessageSubject to "Test email"
set theRecipient to "email@test.com"
set theMessageContent to theData
set theMessageAttachment to newPath

tell application "Mail"
    activate
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:theMessageSubject, content:theMessageContent & linefeed & linefeed}
    tell theMessage
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:theRecipient}
        make new attachment with properties {file name:theMessageAttachment as alias} at after the last word of the last paragraph
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Why are you setting `AppleScript's text item delimiters` to `return`? **macOS** typically used a _line feed_ character, so it should be set to `linefeed`, not `return`.  Also, when using `AppleScript's text item delimiters` you should always _set_ it back to `{}` or `""`. That said, and based on what you have said, I see no good reason for you to be setting `AppleScript's text item delimiters` to begin with. Additionally, if `mockUPPath.txt` has a single line of text, then there is no need to be using `paragraphs of` as a simple `read` _command_ will return the single line of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the most reliable way to interact with read/write API is to coerce the path to `«class furl»` and delete the `file` keyword.

Second of all most of the text files are UTF 8 encoded. If so read it `as «class utf8»`

The error occurs because you cannot coerce a POSIX path to alias. You need an extra step

`Text item delimiters` makes no sense, read the body text as one string and get the first item of the `thePath`.

```
set theFile to ((path to desktop as text) & "mockUPText.txt") as «class furl»
set theData to (read theFile as «class utf8»)

set myPath to ((path to desktop as text) & "mockUPPath.txt") as «class furl»
set thePath to paragraphs of (read myPath as «class utf8»)
set newPath to (POSIX path of (path to desktop folder)) & item 1 of thePath

set newAlias to POSIX file newPath as alias -- if the file doesn't exist you'll get an error


--Email

set theMessageSubject to "Test email"
set theRecipient to "email@test.com"
set theMessageContent to theData
set theMessageAttachment to newAlias

tell application "Mail"
    activate
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:theMessageSubject, content:theMessageContent & linefeed & linefeed}
    tell theMessage
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:theRecipient}
        make new attachment with properties {file name:theMessageAttachment} at after the last word of the last paragraph
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I'll assume since your _code_ errors out,  you did not actually test it with real _files_, _folder_, and _information_ presented in the OP.

Comment: @user3439894 I know there are issues with the `paragraphs` but my suggestion answers the question.

Comment: The bottom line is the _code_ you posted does not work and errors out, and therefore IMHO it does not really answer the question!

Comment: It still errors out because you are not actually testing the _code_ against the real world information presented in the OP.

Comment: @user3439894 I **did** test the script. What errors are you talking about?

Comment: It error on `read myPath as «class utf8»` in `set thePath to paragraphs of (read myPath as «class utf8»)` -- **error** "Can’t make file \"Macintosh HD:Users:me:Desktop:mockUPPath.txt\" into type file." number -1700 from file "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Desktop:mockUPPath.txt" to file

Comment: @user3439894 This error occurs if you forget to coerce the path(s) to `as «class furl»`. My script works.

Comment: If I create the _files_ and _folder_ using the information presented in the OP and copy and paste the _code_ in your answer into **Script Editor** and run it, it errors out. So how is "This error occurs if you forget to coerce the path to `as «class furl»"` relent? Your _code_ either works or it doesn't and in my testing it doesn't!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you presented in your OP, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me as tested in **Script Editor**.

First I did the following:

- Created a *folder* on my **Desktop** named **Name_Mock-up** containing a screenshot of the *example* **AppleScript** *code* in **Script Editor** naming it **555.jpg**
- Created a *file* on my **Desktop** named **mockUPText.txt** with a single line of *text*, **Name_Mock-up/555.jpg**.

The ran the *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set theFile to ((path to desktop as text) & "mockUPText.txt") as alias
set theData to read theFile

set myPath to theFile
set thePath to read myPath
set newPath to (POSIX path of (path to desktop folder)) & thePath

set theMessageSubject to "Test email"
set theRecipient to "email@test.com"
set theMessageContent to theData
set theMessageAttachment to newPath

tell application "Mail"
    activate
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:theMessageSubject, content:theMessageContent & linefeed & linefeed}
    tell theMessage
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:theRecipient}
        make new attachment with properties {file name:theMessageAttachment} at after the last word of the last paragraph
    end tell
end tell
```

---

Here is a screenshot of the result of running the *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

[image]

**Note:** That all said, I would not necessarily *code* it in this manner and have only presented this to correct some of the *code* you originally posted as mentioned in part by my comment to your OP.